# dart2js attempting to compile css?

Tags: angular, dart, dart-pub, dart2js

It looks as though `dart2js` is trying to compile bootstrap's css files. I've tried to google the issue, but I couldn't find anything useful. I guess that's because I'm not really sure what I should be googling.

My last project went fine, and because I was using all the same libraries in this one, I just copied the `pubspec.yaml`.

```
me@my_computer$ pub build
```

---

#### Pub Build Output:

```
Loading source assets... 
Loading angular2/transform/codegen, dart_to_js_script_rewriter, observe and smoke/src/default_transformer transformerLoading angular2/transform/codegen, dart_to_js_script_rewriter, observe and smoke/src/default_transformer transformers... 
Loading angular2 transformers... (3.4s) 
Building progress_viewer... 
[Info from Dart2JS]:
Compiling progress_viewer|web/css/bootstrap-3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css.dart...
[Error from Dart2JS]:
web/css/bootstrap-3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css.dart:1:9:
Expected ';' after this.
library progress_viewer_web_css_bootstrap_3.3.6_css_bootstrap.min.css.dart;
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[Error from Dart2JS]:
web/css/bootstrap-3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css.dart:1:44:
Can't have modifier '.3' here.
Try replacing modifier '.3' with 'var', 'final', or a type.
library progress_viewer_web_css_bootstrap_3.3.6_css_bootstrap.min.css.dart;
                                           ^^
[Error from Dart2JS]:
web/css/bootstrap-3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css.dart:1:70:
Can't have modifier '.' here.
Try replacing modifier '.' with 'var', 'final', or a type.
library progress_viewer_web_css_bootstrap_3.3.6_css_bootstrap.min.css.dart;
                                                                     ^
[Warning from Dart2JS]:
web/css/bootstrap-3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css.dart:
Could not find 'main'.
Try adding a method named 'main' to your program.
[Info from Dart2JS]:
Took 0:00:01.104162 to compile progress_viewer|web/css/bootstrap-3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css.dart.
[Info from Dart2JS]:
Compiling progress_viewer|web/css/bootstrap-3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css.shim.dart...
[Error from Dart2JS]:
web/css/bootstrap-3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css.shim.dart:1:9:
Expected ';' after this.
library progress_viewer_web_css_bootstrap_3.3.6_css_bootstrap.min.css.shim.dart;
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[Error from Dart2JS]:
web/css/bootstrap-3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css.shim.dart:1:44:
Can't have modifier '.3' here.
Try replacing modifier '.3' with 'var', 'final', or a type.
library progress_viewer_web_css_bootstrap_3.3.6_css_bootstrap.min.css.shim.dart;
                                           ^^
[Warning from Dart2JS]:
web/css/bootstrap-3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css.shim.dart:
Could not find 'main'.
Try adding a method named 'main' to your program.
[Info from Dart2JS]:
Took 0:00:00.503648 to compile progress_viewer|web/css/bootstrap-3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css.shim.dart.
[Info from Dart2JS]:
Compiling progress_viewer|web/css/bootstrap-3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css.dart...
[Error from Dart2JS]:
web/css/bootstrap-3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css.dart:1:9:
Expected ';' after this.
library progress_viewer_web_css_bootstrap_3.3.6_css_bootstrap.css.dart;
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[Error from Dart2JS]:
web/css/bootstrap-3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css.dart:1:44:
Can't have modifier '.3' here.
Try replacing modifier '.3' with 'var', 'final', or a type.
library progress_viewer_web_css_bootstrap_3.3.6_css_bootstrap.css.dart;
                                           ^^
[Warning from Dart2JS]:
web/css/bootstrap-3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css.dart:
Could not find 'main'.
Try adding a method named 'main' to your program.
[Info from Dart2JS]:
Took 0:00:00.401814 to compile progress_viewer|web/css/bootstrap-3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css.dart.
[Info from Dart2JS]:
Compiling progress_viewer|web/css/bootstrap-3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css.shim.dart...
[Error from Dart2JS]:
web/css/bootstrap-3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css.shim.dart:1:9:
Expected ';' after this.
library progress_viewer_web_css_bootstrap_3.3.6_css_bootstrap.css.shim.dart;
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[Error from Dart2JS]:
web/css/bootstrap-3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css.shim.dart:1:44:
Can't have modifier '.3' here.
Try replacing modifier '.3' with 'var', 'final', or a type.
library progress_viewer_web_css_bootstrap_3.3.6_css_bootstrap.css.shim.dart;
                                           ^^
[Error from Dart2JS]:
web/css/bootstrap-3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css.shim.dart:1:71:
Can't have modifier '.' here.
Try replacing modifier '.' with 'var', 'final', or a type.
library progress_viewer_web_css_bootstrap_3.3.6_css_bootstrap.css.shim.dart;
                                                                      ^
[Warning from Dart2JS]:
web/css/bootstrap-3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css.shim.dart:
Could not find 'main'.
Try adding a method named 'main' to your program.
[Info from Dart2JS]:
Took 0:00:00.383610 to compile progress_viewer|web/css/bootstrap-3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css.shim.dart.
[Info from Dart2JS]:
Compiling progress_viewer|web/main.dart...
[Info from Dart2JS]:
Took 0:00:11.785265 to compile progress_viewer|web/main.dart.
Build failed.
```

---

#### My pubspec.yaml:

This is basically the one that is used on the angular2 getting started [page](https://angular.io/docs/dart/latest/quickstart.html), but with the platform directives added in.

```
name: progress_viewer
description: Just messing with some stuff
version: 0.1.0
environment:
  sdk: '>=1.13.0 <2.0.0'
dependencies:
  angular2: 2.0.0-beta.17
  browser: ^0.10.0
  dart_to_js_script_rewriter: ^1.0.1
transformers:
- angular2:
    entry_points: web/main.dart
    platform_directives:
    - package:angular2/common.dart#CORE_DIRECTIVES
    - package:angular2/common.dart#FORM_DIRECTIVES
- dart_to_js_script_rewriter
```

---

#### My Directory Layout:

I've only been using dart for a couple of weeks, but I followed their directory layout [guide](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/package-layout.html).

```
project_folder/
|- web/
|  |- index.html
|  |- main.dart
|  |- css/
|     |- bootstrap-3.3.6/
|        |- css/
|        |  |- bootstrap.css
|        |  |- bootstrap.min.css
|        |
|        |- fonts/
|           |- glyphicons-halflinks-regular.eot
|           |- glyphicons-halflinks-regular.svg
|           |- glyphicons-halflinks-regular.ttf
|           |- glyphicons-halflinks-regular.woff
|           |- glyphicons-halflinks-regular.woff2
|
|- lib/
|  |- some_component/
|  |  |- some.component.dart
|  |  |- some.component.html
|  |  |- ...( possible other files e.g. .css )
|  |
|  |- ...( other components )
|  
|- pubspec.yaml
|
|- ...( other files )
```

I have listed everything that is under the `bootstrap-3.3.6` directory. There is no such file `web/css/bootstrap-3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css.dart` or `web/css/bootstrap-3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css.shim.dart`

Even though `pub build` doesn't appear to be working for this project, `pub serve` has no problems at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try to exclude the `web/css` directory for the Angular2 transformer:

```
transformers:
- angular2:
    $exclude: ['web/css/**']
    entry_points: web/main.dart
    platform_directives:
    - package:angular2/common.dart#CORE_DIRECTIVES
    - package:angular2/common.dart#FORM_DIRECTIVES
- dart_to_js_script_rewriter
```

Comment: That simple... Thanks. Is there a page that has all of the angular2 options on it?

Comment: It's actually not an Angular feature https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/assets-and-transformers.html#excluding-assets, rather a transformer feature. For Angular this might help https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules_dart/transform/lib/src/transform/common/options.dart and https://github.com/angular/angular/wiki/Angular-2-Dart-Transformer#resolved_identifiers